# SimpleController Issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Can't get SimpleController to read correctly, is there anything I am doing wrong or is this an environment issue?

When I was using ng-init the code was working fine, now not registering at all. I've checked that it matches word-for-word and am a bit mystified, and new to Angular.JS.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">

        Name:
        <br />

        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name | orderBy: city">{{ name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city | lowercase}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script src="../angular/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        function SimpleController($scope){
            $scope.customers = [
            {name:'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix'}, 
            {name: 'Margo Padler', city: 'Denver'}, 
            {name: 'Jane Fonda', city: 'New York City'}
            ];
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[<kbd>This</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/muUQQN6xamhqkvCozZmR?p=preview) works as expected. You are missing `cust.name`. Another thing to note here, if you only want to filter by customer name and not by the city name then the filter has to change as:

```
ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: {'name': name} | orderBy: city"
```

by making sure that the filter applies only to the name.

Answer (score 0):

have you solve it? i'm having the same problem. 
My error is

```
"SimpleController is not a function". got undefined.
```

But maybe yours might be solve with 
from

```
 <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name | orderBy: city
```

to

```
<li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: name | orderBy: 'city'
```

It now works on mine. We need to serve the files so the controller will work.

So you may

or **use cdn to host angular.min.js**

or if you want to **host your own create a server to host your files.**

Comment: It's not reading the files, what is "use can to host angular.min.js"?

Why can't I read the customer data in the script file below? It worked when I was getting the data using ng-init, but not when I have the data structured this way.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful for others like me.

The problem was the syntax, that is deprecated and is not compatible to Angular 1.3

So, here's the right approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
   <title>SimpleController</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="emp in employees">
            {{emp.name}}
        </li>

    </ul>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SimpleController', function($scope){

        $scope.employees = [
        {'name' : 'emp1', 'id' : 'id1'},
        {'name' : 'emp2', 'id' : 'id2'},
        {'name' : 'emp3', 'id' : 'id3'}
        ];
    });
</script>
```

Note: `<html ng-app="myApp">`, `angular.module('myApp', []).controller('SimpleController', function($scope){` and the end of this function: `});` instead of `}`